# Stata: Newvar for multiple equal dates

Tags: stata

I have trouble to generate a new variable which will be created for every month while having multiple entries for every month.

```
date1    x      b
1925m12 .01213 .323
1925m12 .94323 .343
1926m01 .34343 .342
```

Code would look like this `gen newvar = sum(x*b)` but I want to create the variable for each month.

What I tried so far was

to create an index for the date1 variable with

```
sort date1
gen n=_n
```

and after that create a binary marker for when the date changes

with

```
gen byte new=date1!=date[[_n-1]
```

After that I received a value for every other month but I m not sure if this seems to be correct or not and thats why I would like someone have a look at this who could maybe confirm if that should be correct. The thing is as there are a lot of values its hard to control it manually if the numbers are correct. Hope its clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments on your code

1. There's a typo: `date[[_n-1]` should be `date1[_n-1]`
2. In your posted code there's no need for `gen n = _n`.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
clear
set more off

*-----example data -----

input ///
str10 date1    x      b
1925m12 .01213 .323
1925m12 .94323 .343
1926m01 .34343 .342
end

gen date2 = monthly(date1, "YM")
format %tm date2 

*----- what you want -----

gen month = month(dofm(date2))

bysort month: gen newvar = sum(x*b)

list, sepby(month)
```

will help.

But, notice that the series of the cumulative sum can be different for each run due to the way in which Stata `sort`s and because `month` does not uniquely identify observations. That is, the last observation will always be the same, but the way in which you arrive at the sum, observation-by-observation, won't be. If you want the total, then use `egen, total()` instead of `sum()`.

If you want to group by month/year, then you want: `bysort date2: ...`

The key here is the `by:` prefix. See, for example, [Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004) by Nick Cox, and of course, `help by`.

Comment: Naturally I want to emphasise the last paragraph. The nub of the problem seems to be even simpler than implied here, however. The OP already has a monthly date and just needs to group by its distinct values.

Comment: Okay thanks it worked with the bysort command even though I already tried it earlier already and it gave me wrong results probably was due to wrong usage of "sort" before but Im not sure. Anyways thanks for your quick input!

Comment: You need to show us the "wrong" result and tell us why it's "wrong". Please do so if you still have problems.

Comment: The command I used now was: bysort date1: egen rm = sum(logret * x), respectively with my real variables. The commands which I used before I tried the above mentioned method was: sort date1 gen rm = sum(logret*x) without the bys. Now everything is correct so nothing more is wrong, thanks again! Well the usage of code in these command boxes is not ideal but anyways, problem solved!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The two sets of commands are different, so different results are expected. Glad it worked for you. You can upvote/accept the answer if it solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. It will raise your reputation too.

Answer (score 2):

A major error is touched on in this thread which deserves its own answer.

As used with `generate` the function `sum()` returns cumulative or running sums.

As used with `egen` the function name `sum()` is an out-of-date but still legal and functioning name for the `egen` function `total()`.

The word "function" is over-loaded here even within Stata. `egen` functions are those documented under `egen` and cannot be used in any other command or context. In contrast, Stata functions can be used in many places, although the most common uses are within calls to `generate` or `display` (and examples can be found even of uses within `egen` calls).

This use of the same name for different things is undoubtedly the source of confusion. In Stata 9, the `egen` function name `sum()` went undocumented in favour of `total()`, but difficulties are still possible through people guessing wrong or not studying the documentation really carefully.